# How to take data from button click and add them in a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to save every calculation result and the date in user-registration database, and then make a chart from this data. The code for taking the results is:

```
public double doCalories(boolean fem, boolean male, double age, double weight, double feet, double inches){

    DisplayDateTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_test);
    calander = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date = simpledateformat.format(calander.getTime());
    DisplayDateTime.setText(Date);


    double bmrResult = 0;
    double height_in_inches;

    if (MainActivity.unit_is_gram){
        weight = weight * 2.2;
    }

    if (MainActivity.unit_is_meter){
        height_in_inches = 0.39370* inches; //actually is 0.39370 * centimeters
    }

    else height_in_inches = (feet*12)+inches;

    if (fem == true) {

        bmrResult = 10*(weight/2.2)+6.25*(height_in_inches*2.54)-5*age-161;
    }

    else if (male == true){


        bmrResult = 10*(weight/2.2)+6.25*(height_in_inches*2.54)-5*age+5;
    }



    return bmrResult;
}
```

The code for user database in DataBase Activity is:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

// User table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// User Table Columns names
private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";


// create table sql query
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";
```

How can i combine the database with the results? I know that i have to add fields in database but i dont know what kind of fields and how to take the data from the Calories Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want an additional table, say named readings that will have a reference to the respective user, the date/time of the reading and the result and perhaps the values used.

So perhaps have :-

```
// Reading Table name
private static final String TABLE_READING = "reading";

//Reading Table Column Names
private static final String COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE = "reading_user_reference";
private static final String COLUMN_READING_DATETIME = "reading_datetime";
private static final String COLUMN_READING_AGE = "reading_age"; //<<< shouldn't really be needed as Age could be calculated if date of birth were stored in g user_table
private static final String COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT = "reading_weight";
private static final String COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_FEET = "reading_height_feet";
private static final String COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_INCHES = "reading_height_inches";
private static final String COLUMN_READING_RESULT = "reading_calories"; //<<< could do without

//Create Reading Table SQL
private static final String CREATE_READING_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_READING +
                "(" +
                COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_READING_DATETIME + " TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                COLUMN_READING_AGE + " REAL," +
                COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT + " REAL," +
                COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_FEET + " INTEGER," +
                COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_INCHES + " INTEGER," +
                COLUMN_READING_RESULT + " REAL" +
                ")";
```

You would then want to be able to add a reading so perhaps have (note two signatures allowing default datetime (i.e. now) or a specific datatime to be given) :-

```
//Add using specific timestamp
public long addReading(
        long user,
        long timestamp,
        double age,
        double weight,
        double height_feet,
        double height_inches,
        double result) {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE,user);
    if (timestamp != 0) {
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_DATETIME,sdf.format(date));
    }
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_AGE,age);
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT,weight);
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_FEET,(int) height_feet);
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_INCHES,(int) height_inches);
    cv.put(COLUMN_READING_RESULT,result);
    return db.insert(TABLE_READING,null,cv);
}

//Add user timestamp deault i.e. date/time now
public long addReading(long user,
                       double age,
                       double weight,
                       double height_feet,
                       double height_inches,
                       double result) {
    return addReading(user,0,
            age,
            weight,
            height_feet,
            height_inches,
            result
    );
}
```

- **Note** how the signature is similar to your `doCalories` method.

Here's an example method that will return results along with the user details :-

```
public Cursor getAllResultsWithUserDetails() {
    String[] columns_to_include_in_cursor = new String[]{
            COLUMN_USER_ID,
            COLUMN_USER_NAME,
            COLUMN_USER_EMAIL,
            "datetime(" + COLUMN_READING_DATETIME + ") AS reading_taken",
            COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT,
            COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_FEET + "||'feet '||" + COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT_INCHES+"||'inches' AS height",
            COLUMN_READING_RESULT
    };
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
            TABLE_READING +
                    " JOIN " +
                    TABLE_USER +
                    " ON " +
                    TABLE_USER + "." +  COLUMN_USER_ID +
                    " = " +
                    TABLE_READING + "." + COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE,
            columns_to_include_in_cursor,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            COLUMN_READING_DATETIME + " DESC"
    );
}
```

#### Notes

- The resultant(equivalent) SQL would be :-

  - `SELECT user_id, 
    user_name, 
    user_email, 
    datetime(reading_datetime) AS reading_taken, 
    reading_weight, 
    reading_height_feet||'feet' ||reading_height_inches||'inches' AS height, 
    reading_calories 
    FROM reading 
    JOIN user ON user.user_id = reading.reading_user_reference 
    ORDER BY reading_datetime DESC`

Here's an additional method that will display the results (i.e  it uses the `getAllResultsWithUserDetails` method) in the log:-

```
public void logAllResults() {
    Cursor csr = getAllResultsWithUserDetails();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("RESULTS",
                "Name = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_NAME)) +
                        " (id=" +
                        String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_ID))) + ") " +
                        "\n\tDate/Time of Reading = " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("reading_taken")) +
                        "\n\tWeight = " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT)) +
                        "\n\tHeight = " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("height")) +
                        "\n\tCalories = " +
                        csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_READING_RESULT))
                );
    }
    csr.close();
}
```

Putting this together for demonstration (the above code is in a DBHelper (i.e. a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) named DBHelper) and the following is in an activity :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DBHelper dbhlpr = new DBHelper(this);
    dbhlpr.addUser(
            "Fred",
            "fred@fredmail.com","" +
                    "fredspassword"
    );
    dbhlpr.addReading(1,23,65.7,6,2,4567.78);
    // Add with specific date time (2018-04-30 12:45:00)
    dbhlpr.addReading(1,1525092300, 23,68.2,6,1,5678.67);
    dbhlpr.logAllResults();
}
```

1. First the normal activity stuff i.e  call the super method and set the layout for the activity.
2. Instantiate the DBHelper class.
3. Add a user named Fred with an email of fred@fredmail.com etc
4. Add a reading using the default date/time.
5. Add a reading using a given date/time.
6. Display the reading results

#### Result

The result from **`logAllresults`** is :-

> ```
> 05-09 01:41:37.878 2092-2092/fred.caloriecalc D/RESULTS: Name = Fred (id=1) 
>       Date/Time of Reading = 2018-05-09 01:41:37
>       Weight = 65.7
>       Height = 6feet 2inches
>       Calories = 4567.78
>     Name = Fred (id=1) 
>       Date/Time of Reading = 2018-04-30 12:45:00
>       Weight = 68.2
>       Height = 6feet 1inches
>       Calories = 5678.67
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the extremely analytic answer and the big efford. I m almost sure that you covered all i need! I have to understand it as i m not familiar with sqlite  and i dont understand exactly where to put the code, ii l give it a try and i ll inform you.Thank again and one more time!

Comment: All of the code bar the last block of code would be in the DBHelper. The last block was used to demonstrate/test the code and was in an activity.

Comment: So i have to use addreading in my calorie activity and in my user activity to populate the database?

Comment: using addReading in the Calories activity sounds right, i.e. you'd use addReading where you get the input for the readings. I can't see that you'd use it in the user activity though.

Comment: I follow this tutorial http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-login-and-register-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. It may be that you added the code but you are getting table not found. If so easiest way is to a) delete the App's data or b) uninstall the App and then c) rerun the App. If it's how to call addReadings then you create an instance of the DBHelper in the activity and use that (see last block of code). It should have nothing to do with the user activity (other thann you would obviously get the appropriate user's id in the Calories activity)

Comment: Exactly this is my problem. I dont have something to get user id in calories activity as its an activity to calculate the calories. Users are created at login. So i dont know how to connect them.

Comment: You could add a Spinner to the calories activity from which to select the user. However, if you login to a user then you'd know the user when they login so then it would be a matter of determining that user. In which case you could pass the user via an intent extra when starting the calories activity.

Comment: As you are very familiar with databases, actually i need only weight, curent date and result of calories. Wouldnt be easier if i add this fields in the user table? Then il intent the user in my BaseActivity and try to get the data from calories Activity. Have in mind that i have 4 more measures that i need the results and date.Or is better to have a second table with weight, date and result of every neasurement?

Comment: If you want historical data (for the chart) then I'd suggest a second table as proposed.